# Flash MX projection works on XP but not on windows 7

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, seeing as I don't currently have any code to share, but perhaps someone has an insight.

I have a very old Flash MX projection (.exe file) that was written and compiled in flash MX 2004. It's a simple interactive app - a test where a user picks an answer to a question and pushes ENTER to move to the next question.

The projection works fine on WinXP SP3 but doesn't work in win7, failing with a "class not registered" error.

It does work after I install flash player activex (I tried installing the latest, and also legacy version 6 r71), but then it doesn't register any keyboard commands and crashes a short while after a key is pressed.

Any idea what can be causing this?
So far I've tried fiddling with IE security settings, disabling DWM and windows themes, compatibility settings, etc., with no luck.

Also, despite the fact that the compiled projection is supposed to have all necessary components to run inside, it doesn't run if flash.ocx isn't registered. Isn't that weird?

Any help will be appreciated. I know this is old stuff and no one promises compatibility etc. And I don't even have the code as of now (not sure I can find it; assume I can't) - but this app is somewhat important to my company and this really seems like a "small" issue - if I could just find it...

Update - it kinda works if install the latest flash player and run it in compatibility mode - but it hangs after about a minute, regardless of what i do.
if i run it without compatibility mode, it doesn't run with a "library not registered" error.

Comment: That is odd.  Don't know why it'd be failing, but in case you can't find another solution, try recompiling it by first decompiling the version you have with http://www.sothink.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to repackage it.

1. Extract SWF from projector executable, for example, using [this tool](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/02/Extract-SWF-files-from-Flash-Executables).
2. Get the newest [standalone Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and check if your .swf-file works with it.
3. Now export new projector file.

If this doesn't work for you, the only other way to do this is to recompile your .swf from source.

Comment: I have the SWF files outside the projection, they don't run in either IE or CHROME using the latest flash player. I'm afraid i'm gonna have to dig for the sources and recompile them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ale's solution.

Have you tried Window's compatibility options to run the .exe as it would in an older compatibility mode ? This may work.

Comment: Tried, see in the question - it runs fine but hangs after a little while. Seems like some sort of memory leak or some other OS security related issue that's caused by the compatibility mode.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I'm afraid you're running out of options. It's a bit of a shame that you don't have the original swf file.

Comment: I have the SWF, they don't work either. What I don't currently have is the original FLA sources which I can import into a newer flash studio and recompile into a more modern SWF version.

Comment: And this new most modern swf file can't be run on windows 7?

Comment: Nope. I think it's because some of the functions used in the original flash mx 2004 implementation for either buttons or screen changes are deprecated or considered unsecure in later flash editions and/or windows 7 security, and are therefore blocked.